# What is the difference between these ES6 import methods?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

What is the difference between these import methods?

Method 1:

```
import {sum, pi} from "lib/math";
```

Method 2:

```
import exp, {pi, e} from "lib/mathplusplus";
```

The es2015 docs showed these two examples, and I can't figure out the purpose of the curly braces.  It seems like all of the things listed after import will be assigned to the `window` object anyway.

Docs for reference: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/

Comment: The first imports named exports `sum` and `pi`. The second imports the default export as `exp`, and also named exports `pi` and `e`.

Comment: In case you're interested in learning more about the differences, an excellent resource is the following: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch3.md#modules

Answer (score 13, accepted):

modules can export multiple things.  Modules can also have a single "default" export.

`import exp from "somelib";`

This assigns the *default* export of `somelib` to the variable `exp`.

`import {a, b} from "somelib";`

This assigns the non-default named exports `a` and `b` to local variables `a` and `b`.

`import exp, {a, b} from "somelib";`

Assigns the default export to `exp` and the named exports to `a` and `b`.

`import * as somelib from "somelib";`

Takes all of the named exports of somelib and assigns them as an object to the local variable `somelib`, which means you will have `somelib.a`, `somelib.b`, etc.

This is a very good resource for the topic: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `exp` is the `default` module to be imported, named `exp`. `pi` and `e` are wrapped in curly braces because they are not defaulted.

In [this](https://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/) example, you defined a default module:

```
export default function(x) {
  return x + x;
}
```

And import is without curly braces, naming it whatever you want:

```
import double from 'mymodule';
double(2); // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Modules can `export` in two different ways. They can use `default`, or just perform a standard `export`

```
export default function exp(value, power) {}
export const pi = 3.14159
```

When you `import` from a module you need to use the curly braces to capture non-default exports. If you want the default export, you don't need the braces.

```
import exp, {pi} from "lib/mathplusplus";
```